# MongoDB: dilute collections when mongo is down

Tags: mongodb

as you all must know very well- mongo service is stopped when disk space reaches full capacity.

my question is- if and how can I dilute \ delete a collection while the mongo service is down?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for but to overcome from this situation you can follow below:

1. Copy you data dir to another location where you have space and delete any `.lock` file if exists.
2. Now you can try to start `mongo` with pointing to new dir like and repair below

   mongod --dbpath  --port

   db.repairDatabase()

Once service is up, you can do whatever you want to do.

Comment: thanks for the reply, and sorry for the late response. what I am hoping to accomplish is to delete some collections\data - clearing some space and allowing mongo to come back online without migrating data to another directory. 

currently I am thinking somewhere along the line of finding out which .wt file belongs to which collection and deleting it..

Comment: @asktyagi Repair is equivalent to salvage and should not be used as a strategy to reclaim disk space in modern versions of MongoDB. In general, repair should be a last resort where you do not have another viable copy of the data . The WiredTiger storage engine may be able to release unused space using the [`compact` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/), but note that this command will also block all other operations for the database containing the collection being compacted.

Comment: @GKman There are integrity checks for the files in your dbpath, so you definitely do not want to directly remove any .wt files. A much better strategy would be to monitor free disk space so you can free space preemptively (eg by dropping unused collections or indexes as your disk usage approaches 100%) rather than waiting until the situation is critical. If you do run out of space on a standalone node, you could restart on an alternative port (so your applications won't try to insert/update data), free up some disk space with collection or index drops, and then restart on the normal port.